# A comparative look at the speed of execution of ADO.NET and LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, ado.net

As part of a final year project for a BSc in Computing I'm testing the speed of execution of 2 queries.
One is written in LINQ and the other in ADO.NET and they are inserting information into a database.
After testing it was observed that ADO.NET is evidently faster than LINQ but the speed difference is in milliseconds.
So the question is this, at what point do you think people delays or differences in speed become apparent to human beings? 500 milliseconds, a second, 2, 5? 
At what point does the delay of a program warrant the use of a quicker alternative. 
Any and all feedback would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow need to be specific, answerable, and unsubjective questions.  Subjective questions asking for opinions, polls, etc. are not considered appropriate for this site, so your question will most likely end up being closed soon for that reason.  While the question is somewhat interesting, it is simply such a touchy type of question that SO has deemed it out of scope for the site.

Answer (score 2):

You must consider the overall context. Does the difference in execution speed outweigh the difference in time to write, maintain, understand, train new developers in one version of the code vs. the other?

Answer (score 1):

The usual rule of thumb is that 100ms is where a user's perception of "immediate" ends.  Beyond that, it's very context-dependent - the application is slow if the user thinks it's slow.  If the user thinks it's slow, you should investigate making it faster.